# Setting up application and resource folders in sub virtual application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am looking to use the below asp.net 4.0 web application structure but not quite sure how to achieve my result as explained below. What configuration will be needed to handle path issues for referencing both. For example ~/css/style.css needs to dig into the WEBSITE. I know I will have to create a helper for RESOURCES -- WebResourcePath("images/image1.jpg") returns full path if that works in a separate virtual directory?

```
Default Web Site
    >SAR-GROUPS
        SARGROUPS_WEBSITE
        SARGROUPS_RESOURCES
```

All website files like aspx, js, css, etc. normal web files go in the WEBSITE folder. The RESOURCES folder will contain other files like pdfs, xml, txt, images, and files . These files will not need to be uploaded or updated during deployments and can remain untouched. When I deploy the WEBSITE I only need to delete the WEBSITE folder and copy the new precompiled folder in SAR-GROUPS again. I have to deploy like this as it is automated deployment from scrips that run so this is an xcopy deployment.

Does anyone have good practices or a working setup to achieve this. I am not looking at alternate methods unless it cannot be done or the other way is much better for auto builds.

Thanks

Comment: wondering why there is still a running bounty when you already have accepted answer ? are you still looking for some more answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files in the SARGROUPS_WEBSITE directory need to reference resources in the SARGROUPS_RESOURCES directory then why not just make the SARGROUPS_RESOURCES virtual directory inside the SARGROUPS_WEBSITE directory? This way you can point the SARGROUPS_RESOURCES virtual directory at a physical location on the disk and delete the contents of SARGROUPS_WEBSITE without touching the resources.

So structure would be

```
Default Web Site
    >SAR-GROUPS
        SARGROUPS_WEBSITE
            SARGROUPS_RESOURCES
```

But the physical structure could be anything

You can then reference them like

```
~/SARGROUPS_RESOURCES/css/style.css
```

*untested

**EDIT**

You've totally not understood my answer and/or virtual folders.

Physical structure example:

```
D:\Inetpub\WEBSITE
D:\Inetpub\RESOURCES
```

IIS structure:

```
IIS Root -> Site (that is a website and points to D:\Inetpub\WEBSITE)
IIS Root -> Site > Resources (that is a virtual directory and points to D:\Inetpub\RESOURCES)
```

Comment: That's what we do now and don't want to do that in the future. Mainly because when we run scripts it deletes SARGROUPS_WEBSITE and all subfolders. The resources we dont want to delete and re-establish write permission on some folders and other stuff.

Comment: LOL Yeppers missed it until I read your comment then I was like dang I knew that but my mind was thinking of some different logic. I must have been thinking too deep. One of those moments I suppose, it has been a busy month and too much stuff going on.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can actually take it further by having a virtual folder for each resource folder like 'css' or 'images' this way you could keep urls simple and reference with '~/css'. Really though seems to me like I'd look at the deployment process! Im using MSDeploy at my current job and it does the trick, but you can go more complex/enterprise